# Why do I get "Error response from daemon: denied" when trying to pull an image from ghcr.io

Tags: github-actions

I have two repositories. A and B.

Inside A, I have a docker image. Let's say it's name is `ghcr.io/org/a`

Inside B, I have an action that wants to use this package. Both repos are private.

Here's my action code:

```
    - name: Log in to GitHub Container Repository
    run: |
      echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
    - name: Pull the image
    run: |
      docker pull ghcr.io/org/a:latest
```

As you can see first I log into ghcr.io and I get the `Login succeeded` message. Then I want to pull the image from my other repo.

But I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: denied

However, when I login into ghcr.io from my own machine, I have access to both repositories and I can pull any image from any private repository of mine.

Why GitHub Action from B can not pull image from A in spite of being logged in?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this same problem, but the following worked for me:

First, as @SalTorre suggests, I needed to give `org/b` explicit access to the package via the interface at

```
https://github.com/orgs/org/packages/container/a/settings
```

Next, in the image repository (`org/a` in your case), I needed to specifically grant permission to each user (or a set of teams containing said users) who need to initiate the workflow(s) in GHA that use the image. This is because authentication uses the credentials of `${{ github.actor }}`, which is the specific GitHub Actions user who initiated the workflow.

The URL for doing this is here:

```
https://github.com/org/a/settings/access
```

With these two permissions set, my workflows were able to use my custom-built containers.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error even though I granted read access of package in repo a to repo b.

```
Starting xxx service container
  /usr/bin/docker --config /home/runner/work/_temp/.docker_4a0e5f4d-beda-48eb-9580-eb88fec51e3d login ghcr.io -u user --password-stdin
  /usr/bin/docker --config /home/runner/work/_temp/.docker_4a0e5f4d-beda-48eb-9580-eb88fec51e3d pull ghcr.io/onstructive/xxx/xxx:0.1.9-native
  Error response from daemon: denied
  Warning: Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 9.427 seconds before retry.
```

Then I figured out that my workflow in repo b, that tries to pull an image from packages in repo a, need to declare its permission.

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      packages: read # <-- this was missing and solved the problem
```

Comment: This did it for me. It also seems that not specifying `permissions` explicitly will assume "base/default permissions" which seemed to work for me. Only when I explicitly defined some permissions, leaving out `packages` did it begin to fail.

Comment: That cased incorrect syntax error for me. According to docs (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) it should be a category, and inside you should have permission config, like
```
permissions:
  packages: read

But that shouldn't be needed, since even restrictive policy provides read access :\
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you give repo B explicit access to the package?

https://github.com/orgs/<ORG_NAME>/packages/container/<PACKAGE_NAME>/settings

Comment: I am having this same problem and I _did_ give the relevant repos explicit access to the package at that same URL.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to `Configure SSO` for the token. Try that.

Comment: Yatta! This was it.